# Placing a variable inside single quotes

Tags: variables, import

I have a simple data import script I'm running in MSSQL. If I statically assign the data filename to be imported, it works great.

`BULK
INSERT TRACKED_IMPORT
FROM 'C:\SQLIMPORT\DATAFILE.CSV'
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a')`

However, I'd like to use a variable instead of a static filename.  Something like this:

```
DECLARE @IMPORTFILENAME VARCHAR(30) = 'C:\SQLIMPORT\DATAFILE.CSV';
BULK
INSERT TRACKED_IMPORT
FROM @IMPORTFILENAME
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a')
```

When I do that, I get the following errors:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near '@IMPORTFILENAME'.

Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Is there a way to allow for a variable filename?

Comment: you should create a tag with the language you are using...